# Encode a query string in R

Tags: r, urlencode

Here is a query string that I use to plug into a form:

```
team,site,week,day,date,o:team,line,points,o:points@season=2011
```

and here is the resulting string that is passed to the website:

```
team%2Csite%2Cweek%2Cday%2Cdate%2Co%3Ateam%2Cline%2Cpoints%2Co%3Apoints%40season%3D2011
```

I know that R is a very powerful language.  Are there any functions that would encode this for me?  I figure I could write a function to mimic this output, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`curlEscape` in package `RCurl` does what you want:

```
> library(RCurl)
Loading required package: bitops
> curlEscape("team,site,week,day,date,o:team,line,points,o:points@season=2011")
[1] "team%2Csite%2Cweek%2Cday%2Cdate%2Co%3Ateam%2Cline%2Cpoints%2Co%3Apoints%40season%3D2011"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the `URLencode()` function which is part of the base `utils` package:

```
> URLencode('team,site,week,day,date,o:team,line,points,o:points@season=2011', reserved=TRUE)
[1] "team%2Csite%2Cweek%2Cday%2Cdate%2Co%3Ateam%2Cline%2Cpoints%2Co%3Apoints%40season%3D2011"
```

Just be sure to set `reserved=TRUE` if you want all of the punctuation to be encoded as well.