# PowerBI Embed URL filter unicode for FieldName - Product #

Tags: r, powerbi, querystringparameter

Problem Statement: I'm creating a dynamic application in which user select inputs and they are passed into Embed URL to filter data. But the column(Field) name in my dataset(Table) used in PowerBI is having space and number sign in its name. Example: `Product #`

`?filter=Inventory/Product # eq 'PROD001'`

Here `Inventory` is Table Name and `Product #` is Field Name. This gives error as when passing Field Name in URL it gives error.

I want to know how to convert it to unicode so that can be used in my URL.
%20 is for space *x0020*
%23 is for number sign *x0023*

Comment: You're probably looking for URL escaping, not any kind of Unicode. If you're building a URL to an external application *inside* PBI, try `Uri.BuildQueryString`/`Uri.EscapeDataString`. If you need to pass data to a PBI report URL, escape it properly yourself (for example, `Product #` should be `Product %23`); the way to do this depends on what technology you're using.

Comment: I'm doing that in R, so need that unicode to work for space and hash(#) together between Product and No sign(#)

Comment: *What* is the thing you're doing in R, and if it's really R we're talking about rather than PowerBI in general, can you show code and tag your question with `r`?

Comment: I'm embedding a powerBI dashboard in R and trying to filter the data by passing values to slicer fields in powerBI

Comment: OK, so what you really need is R code to build a URL that applies query string escaping, correct? Does this answer your question? [Encode a query string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031370/encode-a-query-string-in-r)

Comment: It's more of a PowerBI  query string parameter issue. As 'Product #' is not recognised in URL for powerBI dashboard. Space (_x0020_) and number sign (_x0023_) together are not working in URL

Comment: OK, that's getting somewhere. So what you're *really* after is the URL escaping scheme described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-url-filters), right? That is, your final result needs to be `?filter=Inventory/Product_x0020# eq 'PROD001'` *before* query string escaping, and `?filter=Inventory%2FProduct_x0020%23%20eq%20%27PROD001%27` *after* query string escaping (I'm not sure if `#` is special in names, if it is, you'd need `Product_x0020_x0023`).

Comment: Sorry, that's `Inventory/Product_x0020_#` or `Inventory/Product_x0020__x0023_`, upon re-reading -- the page isn't helping by sometimes incorrectly rendering `_` as Markdown italics.

Comment: Yes that's my concern, for above both ways it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Does `?filter=Inventory%2FProduct_x0020__x0023_%20eq%20%27PROD001%27` work? This is escaping `Product #` per the naming rules, and then the rest according to query string escaping.

Comment: I will say the documentation is quite awful here, and it would be hard for anyone to immediately get it right based on nothing but reading that. I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/issues/3939) to hopefully get it fixed.